# JSF -- Filter for javax.faces.resource text replacements

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I'm working with Tomcat7 on JSF 2.17 Mojarra. I'd like to place a servlet filter in front of CSS and Javascript requests to /javax.faces.resource/* to rewrites certain text references in our development and rc environments. I don't seem to be able to alter these CSS and Javascript files using a traditional servlet filter. Is there some other way to accomplish this?

For example, I'm looking to replace references to urls found inside the CSS files from:
prod.ourdomain.com
to
dev.ourdomain.com

something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to override `HttpServletResponse#getOutputStream()` with a custom `ServletOutputStream` which writes to a local buffer and then do a string replacement in there and finally write the modified string to the response. This is quite some code, so here are some helpful classes to assist you further:

- [`HttpServletResponseOutputWrapper`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/servlet/HttpServletResponseOutputWrapper.java)
- [`BufferedHttpServletResponse`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/servlet/BufferedHttpServletResponse.java)

Then you can basically implement the filter as follows:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().endsWith(".css.xhtml")) { // If you use *.xhtml as JSF mapping.
        BufferedHttpServletResponse bufferedResponse = new BufferedHttpServletResponse(((HttpServletResponse) response);
        chain.doFilter(request, bufferedResponse);
        String string = new String(bufferedResponse.getBuffer(), response.getCharacterEncoding());
        string = string.replace("http://prod.ourdomain.com", "http://dev.ourdomain.com");
        response.getWriter().write(string);
    }
    else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is however open for further optimization. Instead of buffering the *entire* response, you could also perform the job inside the custom output stream and buffer only the characters starting with `http://prod.ourdomain.com`, and then discard it and write the new string instead and then continue.

---

**Update**: an entirely different alternative, after all actually better, is to use EL straight in the CSS files. CSS resource requests as performed by JSF `<h:outputStylesheet>` namely by default supports EL in CSS files. For example,

```
someSelector {
    background: url("http://#{staging.dev ? 'dev' : 'prod'}.ourdomain.com/image.png");
}
```

Comment: Wow. El is indeed a beautiful solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: If I want to register an el expression globally, where is the best place to do something like that within a JSF app?

Comment: You could use a context init parameter. It's available by `#{initParam}`. E.g. value of `<param-name>staging</param-name>` would be available by `#{initParam.staging}`. You could use an eagerly initiaized application scoped managed bean. You could use a `ServletContextListener` which sets an attribute in `ServletContext`. Etc...